# how to represent in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a class that I did all calculation in it and now I want to represent this data in datagridview what should I do using c#?
that what I did but it didn't work

```
for (int i = 1; i <= cust_num; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Customer_Number"].Value = cust_num.ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Time_between_Arrival"].Value = inter_Arrival_time.ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["service_Time"].Value = service_Time.ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Arrival_Time"].Value = rand_inter_Arrival.ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Time_Service_Beg"].Value = Arrival_Time.ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ServiceNum"].Value = service_number.ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["service_Time"].Value = rand_service_time.ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Time_service_End"].Value = finsh_time.ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Waiting_Time"].Value = waiting_time.ToString();
   // dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend creating a DataSet or DataTable then binding that to the dataGridView or do a google search and find 1 of 1000's of examples [DataGridView.AddRows](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-add-rows)

Comment: Show us the class!! (If it has its fields laid out as __properties__ you can use a `List<yourClass>` directly as `DataSource` for the DGV.. ((Your code would work if you had those columns created, but it is not a nice road to follow..) - Also: always (read __always__ explain __what__ 'does not work' !!!)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] row = new string[] { cust_num.ToString(), inter_Arrival_time.ToString(), ...... };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

You can add row to datagridview like this

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation on how this code solves the problem